# code for OAuth for evernote in WP7?

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, evernote

Im developing an WP7 app. So i need to access and create some notes with attachments. I cant get the OAuth done. The samples provides along with sdk are using devoloper tokens. But I need Access token. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

As [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97962/seth) pointed out in this another question in the Evernote forum:
http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26377-oauth-c-example/

There exists an C# [example](https://github.com/sethhitch/csharp-oauth-sample) using the [Reactive OAuth library](http://reactiveoauth.codeplex.com/).

I have just found it (and found your question) while looking the same as you. I have downloaded, inserted my API Key values, and worked like a charm. I got a AuthToken for an account I have created in the sandbox.